# A for loop and a sub for loop, store data

Tags: r

With this code I want to get the output of "a" being 10 & 20, and "b" 1 & 2. Then I should get four output, 2 for 10 when b=1/2, and 2 for 20 when b=1/2. Now it is only storing the last, a=20 and then b 1& 2 Im probably confuses right now. But Im happy if someone sees a simple solution! I want to make it with for loops.

```
a <- c(10,20)
b <- c(1,2)
ft <- c()
for(i in 1:length(a)){
  aa <- 10+a[i]
  for(i in 1:length(b))
  {
    aaa <- aa+b[i]
    ft[i] <- aaa
  }}

ft
a 10 b 1 b 2 
a 20 b 1 b 2
```

Comment: After running your code I get `ft` as 31 and 32. What you are trying to do and what is your expected output?

Comment: @ Ronak Shah I want to get the output when using both a=10 and a=20, now I only get the output of a= 20. So the output should be 21,22,31,32. But maybe I then should do it in another way? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the same variable in nested `for` loop. I have changed it to use `i` and `j`. Create a new index variable to store final output. (`k`).

```
a <- c(10,20)
b <- c(1,2)
k <- 0
ft <- numeric(length(a) * length(b))
for(i in 1:length(a)){
  aa <- 10+a[i]
  for(j in 1:length(b))
  {
    k <- k + 1
    aaa <- aa+b[j]
    ft[k] <- aaa
  }}

ft
#[1] 21 22 31 32
```

For this example you can also do it without loops as :

```
c(t(outer(a, b, `+`) + 10))
```